# Dojo: How to create a widget containing a layout widget (border container)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, widget, dojo

I want to create a widget that contains a layoutWidget (for example BorderContainer).

The way that I typically create widgets is to inherit from:

- _WidgetBase
- _TemplatedMixin
- _WidgetsInTemplatedMixin

IE:

```
  define([
        "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
    ],
    function(
        declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin
    ) {
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin] ,{

            templateString: template,
            ...
```

Unfortunately according to the [WidgetsInTemplateMixin](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html):

> The dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin mixin does not support adding layout widgets as children. In particular there are issues with startup() and resize() calls to the children.

I have verified that this does in fact have layout issues.  What is the recommended method to create a reusable widget containing a layoutWidget?

Options:

- Inherit from [_LayoutWidget](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/_LayoutWidget.html) - Can anyone recommend an example of this to follow?
- Inherit from _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin and _WidgetsInTemplatedMixin and workaround issues with resize and startup.  This is what I am presently doing but I am worried about how fragile it may be.  I have found that if I create a resize method on my widget and call resize on the layout then everything works as expected (so far).  I expect that this may not always work and could introduce tricky bugs.

  - Other?

---

To Summarize:

For the purpose of encapsulation and reusability, I want to create a widget.  The widget needs to contain a Layout Widget (BorderContainer in this case).  What is the standard pattern to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could us the following snippet for reference:

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" 
        data-dojo-props="design:'headline'"
        style="width: 100%;height:100%;border:0"
        data-dojo-attach-point="bc">
        <div class="shadow" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="padding:0"
            data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
        ...
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
      data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding:0">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer"
        data-dojo-attach-point="...">

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
          data-dojo-attach-point="..." 
          title="Tab1" selected=true>
            Tab 1</div>

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
          data-dojo-attach-point="..." style="padding:0"
          title="Tab2">
          Tab 2</div>

      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use appropriate javascript code. Make sure you use declare.safeMixin(this, args) and postCreate and startup appropriately.

Also, in case you have rendering issues, you can use the border container's attah point to resize. Essentially, after your startup code, put the follwoing snippet:

```
//kludge: fix for the F12/window resize issue
resize: function () {
    this.bc.resize(arguments);//bc is the atttachpoint name of the BorderContainer
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
```